# Can you use a macro or function in C/C++ to construct incrementing tasks?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

When I create a new software project, I do it via a script which makes the folder, copies and moves some files and generate some source code.

One of the copied files is called `roundRobinTasks.cpp`. Obviously it is ment for round robin tasks like reading the from the serial buffer, handle can bus communication, monitoring emergency switch etc.

This file contains one function which looks as following:

```
void processRoundRobinTasks(void) 
{
    static unsigned char taskCounter = 0;

// HIGH PRIORITY ROUND ROBIN TASKS


// LOW PRIORITY ROUND ROBIN TASKS
    switch( ++ taskCounter )
    {
    default: 
        taskCounter = 0;
        
        /* fill in a task */
        break;

    case 1:
        /* fill in a task */
        break;

    case 2:
        /* fill in a task */
        break;
    }
}
```

This function is called every program cycle in `int main()` and I split tasks into a high priority or a low priority task. Every high prio tasks is run every cycle, only 1 low prio task is run every cycle.

The taskCounter is an ever incrementing static variable. The idea is that for every new task you can add a new case label with an incrementing number. If taskcounter becomes greater than the highest task, the default label will set it back to 0. This prevents the need to pre define the amount of tasks.

To make it look prittier, I was looking into a couple of macros and I quickly arrived at this situation. I already filled in some details of what one could fill in.

```
void foobar()
{
    // code
}

void processRoundRobinTasks(void) 
{
HIGH_PRIORITY_TASKS

    foobar() ; 

LOW_PRIORITY_TASKS

    TASK(1)
        REPEAT_MS( 500 )
        TGL( PORTB, 5 ) ;           // is run every 500ms
        END_REPEAT

    TASK(2)
        REPEAT_MS( 50 )
        handleSomething() ;         // is run every 50ms
        END_REPEAT

    TASK(3)
        doSomethingElse() ;
    
    TASK(4)
        /* fill in a task */

    
END_TASKS
}
```

It compiles fine with these macros and it works the exact same.

```
#define HIGH_PRIORITY_TASKS static unsigned char taskCounter = 0;
#define LOW_PRIORITY_TASKS  switch( ++ taskCounter ) \
                            { \
                            default : \
                                taskCounter = 0 ;

#define TASK(x)             break ; case x:
#define END_TASKS           break ; \
                            }
```

With or without the macros, there is one minor bug possibility. If a user adds or removes a task and forgets to update all the task numbers, there will be tasks which may never be called like in this example.

```
    default: 
        taskCounter = 0;

        /* fill in a task */
        break;

    case 1:
        /* fill in a task */
        break;

    case 3:             // because task 2 does not exist I will never run     
        /* fill in a task */
        break;
```

I am interested in a construct, in which I can simply type `TASK` or `if( Task() )` without a number followed by an actual task to do like:

```
void processRoundRobinTasks(void) 
{
HIGH_PRIORITY_TASKS

    foobar() ; 

LOW_PRIORITY_TASKS

    TASK
        REPEAT_MS( 50 )
        handleSomething() ;         // is run every 50ms
        END_REPEAT

    TASK
        doSomethingElse() ;
    
    TASK
        /* fill in a task */

    
END_TASKS
}
```

I am not limited to calling a function. I essentially can do whatever I want in this code.

I believe that it cannot be done with a function. I for one could not think of anything.

Can something like this be done with a macro?
Are there other constructs for this such as a list with function pointers?

**EDIT:**
For the macro haters. The advantage of this system is that one is not forced to make a function for every single task. imho some things are just too simple to dedicate a function to it.

I have worked with several C++ timer and task scheduler libraries and I came back from them. Though they work well, I was not fond of any of them. I had to create a new timer object for every single timed event. Being an embedded programmer, I sometimes desire for more simplicity. How more stupid simple some things are, the better.

For instance the `REPEAT_MS(interval)` macro, is my best macro ever. I honestly stand by this one, I use it everwhere (except within class methods). Everything what you put between `REPEAT_MS()` and `END_REPEAT` gets repeated every interval time. You do not have to declare new variables, you don't have to make objects for them or initialize and you are not forced to make a function for litterly every little thing. This macro cost four bytes of RAM for every time you use it.

```
#define REPEAT_MS(x)    { \
                            static uint32_t previousTime ;\
                            uint32_t currentTime = millis() ;\
                            if( currentTime  - previousTime >= x ) {\
                                previousTime = currentTime ;
                                // code to be repeated goes between these 2 macros
#define END_REPEAT          } \
                        }
```

I succesfully tried the macros of the given answer and it works really well. Now it does not matter if one forgets to update the numbers.

[image]

If you honestly believe that this is "unreadable" or "messy" I honestly believe that you cannot code. But lets keep our opionions to our selves...

Comment: Please try to avoid the term "C/C++", unless you want to irritate us old geezers. There's no such single language as "C/C++", only the two separate, distinct and very different languages C and C++. Even in the rare cases where a question could apply to both C and C++, only tag the language you're actually program in.

Comment: You can build what is effectively your own language, but it will only be readable by you.

Comment: Usually default is the lat of switch statements.

Comment: "To make it look prittier, I was looking into a couple of macros " **NO**. It made your code an ugly and completely unreadable mess. You need to get rid of these macros immediately. C programmers can read C, they cannot read your secret macro language. Once you've unf*d the macro mess, consider using a table of function pointers instead of a switch.

Comment: You do not fully explain your problem : are you building this file automatically from list of files given by users ? Or ?

Comment: This is similar to what they do in MFC.

Comment: `Can something like this be done with a macro?` Yes. But _why_?

Comment: Is this even C++ related? I mean, have you considered some high level abstractions from C++, C++-specific constructs etc.? To me it seems more like C and macro-exclusive topic.

Comment: If you want to improve your code, try using enum values instead of hard-coded magic numbers.  Or even better, get rid of the switch, take advantage of polymorphism with a class factory or similar, put your tasks in a priority queue or similar and your scheduler / dispatcher will be trivially simple.

Comment: "Macro haters" Yeah well, I only have 20 years of real-world embedded systems C programming experience - particularly experienced when it comes to taking over old rotten code bases where someone incompetent has made a mess but the project/product must live on. Trust me when I'm telling you that if you write macro goo like this in a professional setting, _you will get fired from your job_. If your job is to program real-time systems and you write some naive busy-delay scheduler using hobbyist libraries, _you will get fired from your job_.

Comment: Re. _"Obviously it is ment for round robin tasks like reading the from the serial buffer, handle can bus communication, monitoring emergency switch etc."_  : "round-robin" refers only to the scheduling method, it is not specific to certain types of function or task, and certainly "_monitoring emergency switch_" I would hope would not be round-robin. "stop when it gets around to it" semantics is an  inappropriate response to an emergency in most cases.

Comment: Why not just use an configurable tasklist array with a task func pointer and delay, then a simple loop over this table together with the delay check in order to check the task execution. No need of the macros there. In your code, someone could think of, "Oh I have no high prio tasks, so just start with `LOW_PRIO_TASKS`and then you don't have a taskcounter.

Comment: @kesselhaus you make a good valid point there. I do want to add that a newly assembled project comes with the macro's implemented. The `HIGH_PRIO_TASKS` line is already there. So you could not forget to type it, but it does not forbid one to simply remove the line and gets himself a compiler error.
@Clifford The emergency switch kills the machine electrically and pneumatic. Reading te button in software only lets a red light blink and shows some text. Therefor it is the least important task we have in software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
#define HIGH_PRIORITY_TASKS static unsigned char taskCounter = 1;
#define LOW_PRIORITY_TASKS  switch( taskCounter ) \
                            { \
                            default : \
                                taskCounter = 1 ;

#define TASK(x)                 taskCounter = (x); \
                                break ; \
                            case (x):
#define END_TASKS               taskCounter = 1; \
                                break ; \
                            }
```

The idea is to update `taskCounter` to the next task just before breaking out of the switch. It shouldn't matter if there are gaps in the `taskCounter` values as long as the "first" task `TASK(1)` is present.

Comment: I just replaced the macros by your's and they work well.

Comment: @bask185 Although you accepted this as an answer, I wouldn't personally use something like this. I'd just initialize a static array of function pointers - one function per low priority task with no gaps in the array, and have a static index to iterate through the elements of the array and call the function pointer.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and I will propably use that construction one day. Thing is, I program embedded stuff for 99%. Sometimes a task can be a simple oneliner like reading an input and setting a flag. I am simply not (yet) in the 'mood' to dedicate a function to such simple oneliners.